# Matlab - Sum of array columns

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, sum, series

I'd like to calculate the sum of a columns in a Matrix in Matlab and assign the value to another Matrix without a for loop (as I will be needed to do lots of these with little variations in the sum formula and writing for-loops for each of these would be silly).

Here is what I have so far:
`finalmatrix= [
        symsum((sample1Prime(i)-sample1(i))^2, i, 1, 10);
       ]`

Note this would be one index of the final matrix.

I keep getting an error saying symsum is invalid for arguments of type double.. And a quick Google search tells me that it cannot be used for non-symbolic expressions. But no further solutions are given that meet my requirements.

Essentially what I'm trying to calculate is:
The sum from i = 1 to 10 of sample1Prime(i)-sample1(i))^2 where sample1Prime and sample1 are 10x1 Matrices.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not using `sum` since your variables do not seem to be symbolic ?

Comment: Yes that is why I stated my error. symsum was my initial try and sum doesn't seem to fit my needs. I need to sum every first, second, third....., n row of (sample1Prime-sample1)^2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the cumulative sum:

`cumsum(sample1Prime-sample1.^2)`

If you only need the final sum:

`sum(sample1Prime-sample1.^2)`

Comment: I'm trying to sum only column i. My example of 10x1 Matrices was just there for coherence.

Comment: In that case: `sum(sample1Prime(:,i)-sample1(:,i).^2)`, or `cumsum(sample1Prime(:,i)-sample1(:,i).^2)`

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm :).